# How can I pass informations between the form and the user controls?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, user-controls, windows-forms-designer

I have a problem with my project. Since I do not like it that every Windows Form is a new window I did try to use an different way.

This way I did create an FormGUI which contains the menu and calls the different UserControls. Since we did only learn how to use Windows Forms I do know how to work with them. There I would have changed the constructor of the new Windows Form to pass Data.

But this time I use mainly one Windows Form and different UserControls.

e.g. I have one to add new data, an other one to show data in a datagrid and one to show the data inside of an chart. At least this is the result.

But I do not finde a way to transport informations from the Windows Form into one User Control and how to get them back. In order to use this knowlegde somewhere else.

Does someone knew a tutorial where I can see how it could work? Or could explain it to me.

Since the UI is part of the end project that will be marked I would prefer my new way. But if I can't find a work around I will need to change it so that I would work with different windows form. >_> But really... I do not want the application to open new windows for every task. I would prefer to only show the information in one page.

In my search I did found some tutorials about UI Design with Windows Form but only the design (where a chart would be placed it is only a picture) an not how this will work with real informations.

I hope you could understand my problem...

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that the constructor of the form is something like this

```
private List<MyData> _data;

public MyForm(List<MyData> data)
(
    ...
    _data = data;
)
```

Declare an interface

```
public IDataAware
{
    List<MyData> Data { get; set; }
}
```

and let the user controls implement it. E.g.

```
public MyDataGridUserControl : UserControl
{
    ...

    public List<MyData> Data {
        get { return (List<MyData>)dataGridView1.DataSource; }
        set { dataGridView1.DataSource = value }
    }
}
```

If you are working with a `BindingSource`, access the `BindingSource` instead of the grid control. Now, you can access all your user controls through the same interface. In the form you can create a field

```
private IDataAware _dataUserControl;
```

In a menu item click routine, you could do some thing like this

```
_dataUserControl = new MyDataGridUserControl();
```

in another one

```
_dataUserControl = new MyChartUserControl();
```

But all the user controls implementing `IDataAware` you can do

```
Controls.Add(_dataUserControl);
_dataUserControl.Data = _data;
```

Note: Forms, Controls and UserControls are just classes as any other class, and you can do all the object-oriented things with them as with any c# class. (There are some restrictions with generics, however.)

Comment: At first I thought I would understand it ... but I read it at the moment for mor than twenty times ... and somehow I'm stuck.

Okay, I now have an interface called IDatenBestand and I did implement it in the User Controls. But honestly I do not understand how I have to go from there. 

I mean ... in the Form I have the original lsit and in the UserControl I want to add to this list or use information from it. But how do I know if the Form or the Control has the complete Information?

I do not know if it's time - I'm sitting here since 8 o'clock in the morning. Or something else.

Comment: Please add the relevant code to your question. So far I have to guess what you are doing and it's difficult to tell you more.